# i want to display error message in my multiple step form in jquery

Tags: javascript

I want to display an error message in my multiple step form in jquery if
 I click on next button with out filling any value it should gives error message as soon as enter value error message disappear.if i click on next bttton with out filling any value it should gives error message as soon as enter value error message disappear

```js
function isEmail(str) { // simple email validation
  return /(.+)@(.+){2,}\.(.+){2,}/.test($.trim(str));
}
function isEmpty(str) { // test for empty string
  return $.trim(str) === "";
}
function validate($div) { // validates any div - will not let you leave the div if error
  var $fields = $div.find("input"), hasError = false;
  $fields.each(function() {
    $(this).removeClass("error")
    hasError = this.name=="pword" && isEmpty(this.value);
    if (hasError) {
      $("#pword").addClass("error").focus();
      return false;
    }  
    hasError = this.name=="email" && (isEmpty(this.value) || !isEmail(this.value));
    if (hasError) {
      $("#email").addClass("error").focus();
      return false;
    }  
    hasError = isEmpty(this.value); // the rest of the fields
    if (hasError) {
      $(this).addClass("error").focus();
      return false;
    }  
  })
  return hasError?false:true;
}
$(function() {

  // validate all divs on submit, but actually only necessary to validate thediv the submit is on  
  $("#myForm").on("submit",function(e) { 
    $(".page").each(function() {
      if (!validate($(this))) {
        e.preventDefault(); // stop submission
        return false;
      }
    });
  });

  $(".nav").on("click", function() {
    var $parent = $(this).closest("div");
    var $nextDiv = $(this).hasClass("next") ? $parent.next() : $parent.prev();
    if (validate($parent)) { // is the div this button is on valid?
      $parent.fadeOut(function() { // fade it out and fade the next one in
        if ($nextDiv.length) {
          $nextDiv.fadeIn()
          for (var i=$(".page").length;i> $nextDiv.index(); i--) {
            $("#bar" + i).css({"background-color": "#D8D8D8"}); // we are going backwards          
          }
          $("#bar" + $nextDiv.index()).css({"background-color": "#38610B"});
        }  
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #D8D8D8;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 995px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  font-family: helvetica;
  position: relative;
}

#wrapper .baricon {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 100%;
  padding: 12px;
  background-color: #38610B;
  color: white;
}

#wrapper .progress_bar {
  width: 200px;
  height: 5px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: #D8D8D8;
  display: inline-block;
}

#wrapper form div {
  margin-left: 340px;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 300px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  background-color: #585858;
}

#wrapper form div p {
  color: #F2F2F2;
  margin: 0px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#wrapper form div .form_head {
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

#wrapper form div input[type="text"] {
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: none;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#wrapper form div input[type="button"],
input[type="submit"] {
  width: 80px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  background: none;
  color: white;
  margin: 5px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#user_details,
#qualification {
  display: none;
}

.error { background-color:pink !important}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <br>
  <span class='baricon'>1</span>
  <span id="bar1" class='progress_bar'> </span>
  <span class='baricon'>2</span>
  <span id="bar2" class='progress_bar'> </span>
  <span class='baricon'>3</span>

  <form method="post" action="" id="myForm">
    <div id="account_details" class="page">
      <p class='form_head'>Account Details</p>
      <p>Email Address</p>
      <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder='Email Address'>
      <p>Password</p>
      <input type="text" name="pword" id="pword" placeholder='Password'>
      <br>
      <input type="button" value="Next" class="nav next" />
    </div>

    <div id="user_details" class="page">
      <p class='form_head'>User Details</p>
      <p>First Name</p>
      <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" placeholder='First Name'>
      <p>Last Name</p>
      <input type="text" name="lname" is="lname" placeholder='Last Name'>
      <p>Gender</p>
      <input type="text" name="gender" id="gender" placeholder='Gender'>
      <br>
      <input type="button" value="Prev" class="nav prev" />
      <input type="button" value="Next" class="nav next" />
    </div>

    <div id="qualification" class="page">
      <p class='form_head'>Qualification</p>
      <p>Qualification</p>
      <input type="text" placeholder='Qualification'>
      <p>Hobbies</p>
      <input type="text" placeholder='Hobbies'>
      <br>
      <input type="button" value="Prev" class="nav prev" />
      <input type="Submit" value="Submit">
    </div>
  </form>

</div>
```

Comment: can any one help me

Comment: try required Attribute

Comment: ok can you guide me on that

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/c9vpk4qh/

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jQuery Steps](http://www.jquery-steps.com/Examples#basic-form) plugin for these multiple steps form. This will be very easy to handle.